# Don´t allow domain users to access shared folders on PCs outside the domain in the same LAN

Tags: windows, group-policy, domain, sharing, controller

I have the following problem.

Is there a way to block domain users from accessing folders shared by computers that are not in the domain? By this means there is information leakage
For example:
**Domain_User_One** has his business Lap-top which is within a domain, but when he is at home he has a personal PC there, so that user creates a folder with "everyone" permission from his personal PC, from his Lap-top to company connects to that shared folder and copies information there.

is there a way to block this? in this scenario without using DLP.

Comment: If the business laptop is connected to a domain you can disable file sharing through a group policy.  That is the proper way to prevent the scenario you describe.

Comment: One way could be to block outbound connectivity to SMB ports to any IP addresses that don’t match specific corporate servers. That should be able to be done with the built in windows firewall.

Comment: Appleoddity thanks a lot, That is the solution!